# Some doubts related to the absolute positioning of a div into a relative element

Tags: css, html, xhtml

I am following a tutorial about to the creation of a web template tabless using HTML+CSS and I have some doubts related to the positioning of elements inside my template.

This image represents how my template have to look at the end:

[image]

Now I have to place the horizontal main menu (the green one that is into the header)

The tutorial that I am following say that I have to use the **absolute positioning** to move right the div having id=nav which contains the list with the navigation menu.

To do this thig the tutorial say that I have to do the following thing:

1. Set the position of its parent div as **relative** and set the exact height of this parent div
2. Use the **absolute positioning** for the div having id=nav

So, in my template I must have something like this in the HTML code:

```
        <div id="header">    <!-- HEADER -->
            <div id="logo">     <!-- My Logo -->
                <h1><a href="#">My web site is cool</a></h1>
                <p id="slogan">
                    My web site is finally online
                </p>
            </div>

            <!-- Here go the horizontal main menu -->
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contatti</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And something like this for the CSS code:

```
#header {
    background: #092F85;
    position: relative;
    height: 193px;          /* I set the height of my header */
}   


#nav{
    background: #93D459;
    position: absolute;
    top: 166px;
    right: 0;
}
```

I think that the meaning of the **positioning of the #nav div is easy** (correct me if I'm wrong) and is: the div having id=nav is positioned in absolutely way in the right side (becasue **right: 0;**) of its container and thisdiv is pushed downward by 166px.

Is this reasoning correct?

the thing that I can't understand is: **Why in the parent div (the #header) have I to set the position as relative?**

I think that, generally, when I have to place an element with **position: absolute;** I have to set that it's parent have to be **position: relative;**

But why? What it means?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `position: absolute` on an element it will position it relative to the `<body>` element.  However if you use `position: relative` on one of the elements parents further down the DOM it will be positioned relative to that parent element.  Consider the following

```
#positioned_element
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
}


<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="positioned_element">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

There will be a gap of 10px between the start of the body element and the #positioned_element.  However if you do

```
#container
{
    position: relative;
}

#positioned_element
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
}
```

The 10px gap will now appear between the top of the #container element rather than from the body element because the absolutely positioned element is now positioned relative to #container.

You should also consider using float: right in this case.

Comment: Ok, so what you say me is that if I set the position: relative; property to an element (as #container) this element will be in the same position that it would have without position: relative but now this element (#container) became the point of reference for the absolute positioning of some inner elements. Is it right?
Another question is: "Is it a good way to position an element or it could present some problems? how it behaves in the case of liquid layouts?"

Comment: Yep, spot on you've got it.  It think it depends on what you are building.  In the example you gave using float:right would have achieved the same thing.  Positioning absolutely overrides the default behaviour of the browser so I try not to use it that much.

Answer (score 2):

When you give an element (like your `#nav` element) `position:absolute`, it's positioned in relation to its nearest ancestor that has position `absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed`. If none of its ancestors have any of those position values, it's positioned relative to the initial containing block (see [@Alohci’s comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408507/some-doubts-related-to-the-absolute-positioning-of-a-div-into-a-relative-element/17408583?noredirect=1#comment25287463_17408583)).

Because you want `#nav` to position itself in relation to `#header`, `#header` needs to have `position:relative` to make that happen.

You could give `#header` `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` instead, but then it would no longer take up layout space in the document, and the subsequent elements in the document would move up.

Comment: Ok, now is more clear for me. The only doubt that I have is: if I set the property position: relative; for my div having id=header (for this div I am only setting the position property as relative and not the property top, left, etcetc) so it means that this div is positioned relative to the body element but its position don't change because I have no setted other property as top or left?

Comment: @AndreaNobili: not quite. `position:relative` makes an element be positioned relative to *where it would have have been positioned if it had `position:static`*. So, if you *did* give `div#header` e.g. `left:5px; top:5px;`, it would shift down 5 pixels and left 5 pixels. But yes: if you give an element `position:relative` and don't set its `top`, `left`, `bottom` or `right` properties, then it'll stay where it already is.

Comment: Note that the default is not the body element, but the [initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details). See http://jsfiddle.net/P8p7a/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to get a better grasp on css `position: absolute`

This is a decent write up explaining it: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

(Also, remember that with Web Development there are usually more than one ways to accomplish the same thing.)

Comment: That's not a very helpful answer on its own. It'd help if you added an explanation of `position:absolute` in the answer itself - external links can go away.

Comment: I understand, but it seems to me that op needs a solid understanding of `position:absolute`. Thanks though, I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: sure, they do, but Stack Overflow answers are mainly meant to answer the question asked.